# Select cell according to column and row by xpath

Tags: xpath

I have next table sturcture:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User Role</th>
            <th>Inactive</th>
            <th>Admin Area</th>
            <th>Need Confirm</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Admin</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>True</td>
            <td>False</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Member</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>False</td>
            <td>True</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I select a cell according to column name and row from first column (e.g. select `Admin Area` cell value for `Member`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can guarantee that `User Role` is the first column, then the following will work:

```
//td[count(//th[text()="Admin Area"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1][../td[1]="Member"]
```

Explanation:

- `count(//th[text()="Admin Area"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1` gives you the index of "Admin Area" among the table headers, in this case 3
- `//td[3]` selects all `td` cells in the third column
- `//[../td[1]="Member"]` further qualifies this by selecting only the `td` cells whose sibling in the first column contains `"Member"`